# Toolbar moves up when call finishes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, toolbar

While in a call, if the user wants to use my application, and if the call finishes, and the user is still in the application, the toolbar moves up, well all the view moves up, and so the toolbar now has a space in the bottom. Basically the height "Touch to return to call" has. I am using a toolbar and a navigation controller. The navigation controller moves fine, and everything in the view moves accordingly, the only problem is with the toolbar. So the question is, Is there an event, which is called after the call is finished, so I can set the frame again of my toolbar? I tried this delegate with no luck:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame
```

This one is called only when the toolbar is changing orientation.

[alt text http://is.hn/downloads/IMG_0008.PNG](http://is.hn/downloads/IMG_0008.PNG)
[alt text http://is.hn/downloads/IMG_0009.PNG](http://is.hn/downloads/IMG_0009.PNG)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general setting your auto resize masks properly should fix things.  Could you update with a screenshot to show exactly where the resizing issues are happening?

Comment: You can restructure it such that the toolbar is attached to the bottom and the background view rests on top of it.  It then woud auto-resize while the toolbar would remain fixed.

Comment: That would mean I wouldn't be able to use the toolbar in transparent mode. Is there another way?